# Is There a way to get a element based on where the current scroll is?

Tags: reactjs, scrollbar

I have a bunch of div elements and in want to know if the scroll is at a particular element I am using a custom scrollbar implementation([react-custom-scrollbars](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-custom-scrollbars)).

Here's the working code.
https://codesandbox.io/s/7j28kmoy86

Comment: You might need some library similar to this [react-waypoint](https://github.com/brigade/react-waypoint)

Comment: @VaibhavVishal well thanks! It does work but is there a way to pass data-* attr in waypoint? because I have tried and it doesn't seem to work not even an id you can see that in sandbox url posted in question